# Error using Spark's Kryo serializer with java protocol buffers that have arrays of strings

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kryo

I am hitting a bug when using java protocol buffer classes as the object model for RDDs in Spark jobs,

For my application, my ,proto file has properties that are repeated string. For example

```
message OntologyHumanName 
{ 
repeated string family = 1;
}
```

From this, the 2.5.0 protoc compiler generates Java code like

```
private com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList family_ = com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.EMPTY;
```

If I run a Scala Spark job that uses the Kryo serializer I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList.size(UnmodifiableLazyStringList.java:61)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
... 40 more
```

The same code works fine with spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer.

My environment is CDH QuickStart 5.5 with JDK 1.8.0_60

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with kryo. Were you able to resolve it? Can you please post solution if that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the `Lazy` class with:

```scala
Kryo kryo = new Kryo()

kryo.register(com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.class)
```

Also for custom Protobuf messages take a look at the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219871/993390) for registering custom/nestes classes generated by `protoc`.

Answer (score -1):

I think your RDD's type contains class OntologyHumanName. like: RDD[(String, OntologyHumanName)], and this type RDD in shuffle stage by coincidence. View this: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#kryoserializable kryo can't do serialization on abstract class.

1. Read the spark doc: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization

   ```
   val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(...).setAppName(...)
   conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[MyClass1], classOf[MyClass2]))
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   ```
2. on kryo doc:

   ```
   public class SomeClass implements KryoSerializable {
      // ...

      public void write (Kryo kryo, Output output) {
         // ...
      }

      public void read (Kryo kryo, Input input) {
         // ...
      }
   }
   ```

but the class: OntologyHumanName is generated by protobuf automatically. So I don't think this's a good way to do.

3. Try to use case class replace OntologyHumanName  to avoid doing serialization on class OntologyHumanName directly. This way I didn't try, it's doesn't work possiblly.

   ```
   case class OntologyHumanNameScalaCaseClass(val humanNames: OntologyHumanName)
   ```
4. An ugly way. I just converted protobuf class to scala things. This way can't be failed. like：

   ```
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

   val humanNameObj: OntologyHumanName = ...
   val families: List[String] = humamNameObj.getFamilyList.asScala  //use this to replace the humanNameObj.
   ```

hope resolve your problem above.